# Migrar servidor Tomcat para Wildfly no eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, wildfly

Estou tentando migrar um projeto(Java, HIbernate, JSF, SpringSecurity, CDI, Mysql) que roda atualmente no TOMCAT, para o WILDFLY. Já configurei o “standalone” com a conexão e o Wildfly sozinho inicializa sem erro algum.

Quando inicializo o aplicativo a ser migrado, ele dá erro “error 404”, ou seja, não reconhece o index, nem qualquer outra página, mesmo apontando diretamente no browser.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda dos amigos.

Comment: Qual a estrutura do projeto?

Comment: Amigo, eu já resolvi parte do problema. Alguns dos problemas estavam relacionados a pequenas mudanças no código pom e no web.xml. A única coisa que ficou pendente é que o wildfly muda o nome do link de acesso.

Comment: foce fala contexto da aplicação ?

Answer (score 0):

Por padrão, o Widfly utiliza o nome do pacote implantado como contexto da aplicação. Ex: Se o pacote implantado for minhaaplicao.war, então a aplicação será acessada através da URI  http://host:porta/**minhaaplicacao**.

Para altera o nome do contexto, crie um arquivo na pasta WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
   <context-root>/contextoaplicacao</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Onde "contextoaplicacao" é o nome com o qual você desejar acessar sua aplicação no servidor.

Comment: É exatamente isto Rodrigo. Quando faço o deploy pelo Eclipse, diferentemente do Tomcat, o Wildfly utiliza o artifactId + version. É apenas um detalhe, mas que me levou achar que o app não estava rodando corretamente pois não consegui acessá-lo. Valeu a dica !

Comment: @mrzappabr, se a resposta lhe ajudou, você poderia marcá-la como util? Obrigado!

Comment: Amigo Rodrigo, infelizmente eu não consigo dar o voto. O sistema não permite pois sou novo na casa, pelo menos nos comentários. De qualquer forma, obrigado pelo toque e eu tenho utilizado a dica quando uso o WildFly. Abs.